# group by and order by with linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

There are 2 tables: `Rents` and `People`

I'm new in linq statements programming. Here is my sql query which i want to transform into linq:

```
select top 20 r.partnerid, max(p.PartnerName )
from Rents r join People p on p.Partnerid = r.Partnerid
where r.partnerid > 0 
group by  r.partnerid
order by  count(r.rentid) desc
```

I tried something like this, but I do not know how to get the People.PartnerName into the select statement:

```
var linqQuery = from r in meta.Rents 
             join p in meta.People on r.PartnerId equals p.PartnerId
             where r.PartnerId > 0 
             group r by r.PartnerId into pp
             select new
             {
                 PartnerId = pp.Key,
                 PartnerName = ??? //  PartnerName is a field/column from People
             } 
             // order by ?
```

Comment: Does PartnerName depend on PartnerId? Meaning, all partner objects with the same id, will they have the same name (company)?

Comment: Sorry, PartnerName is a field/column from People

Comment: Will all people that is put into the same group based on partnerid have the same company?

Comment: Yes, PartnerID is PK in People

Comment: And company is depending on partner id? Meaning that all people related to the same partnerid will have the same company? Your question is confusing since you have referred to a Company in the SQL but call it PartnerName in the linq.

Comment: It was my mistake... Company = PartnerName. I edited the question

Comment: And still, **are all people related to the same partnerid having the same company/PartnerName**?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180852/discussion-between-florin-m-and-lasse-vagsaether-karlsen).

Comment: Florin, consider to edit your question so that all comment questions are answered. Try to provide the information that you think people need to answer your question. Don't wait until they ask for this information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like

```
PartnerName = pp.Select(p => p.PartnerName).FirstOrDefault()
```

You will get some further explanation and a running fiddle from here:
[Group by in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq)

Comment: And how can I order descending by Count(r.RentId)?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to get the first one from the grouped list

```
PartnerName = pp.First().PartnerName
```

Or, you could also use max like your original query

```
PartnerName = pp.Max(x => x.PartnerName)
```

Comment: Thanks! And also how can I order the list descending by r.RentId ?

Comment: @FlorinM. Its a bit counterproductive to ask followup questions in comments. Perhaps update your original question or ask a new one.

Comment: I specified in my sql query that I'm using order by descending. I specified also that I want to transform it into linq

Comment: @FlorinM. `orderby [table].[property] [descending],` between groupby and select

Comment: @DragandDrop Yes, if I order by a simple property. But I want the order to be descending based on Count